# Multiple browser windows open automatically while testing with protractor

Tags: google-chrome, automated-tests, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

Recently I found that whenever I run my protractor tests, multiple chrome browser windows pop up automatically. They seem to resemble the command prompt windows [(click here for a screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2JNA.png) and open as each test case is run. Manually closing the windows causes the test to fail. I haven't made any changes to the protractor-conf.js file. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Could you post your protractor config? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The multiple windows were chromedriver instances. Fixed the issue by completely reinstalling the environment (protractor, node.js, chromedriver.exe, jasmine, selenium).

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the config file. shardTestFiles allows multiple instances of browsers to run for your test suite and maxInstances sets the amount of browsers you want to run. See below.

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || 'chrome'),
        'version': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_VERSION || 'ANY'),
        //Allows tests to run in parallel
        shardTestFiles: true,
        //Max amount of browsers
        maxInstances: 10
    },
```